# Dynamic href value

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I am trying to set dynamic href / hyperlinks in my dash application.

Firstly I have this method to get a title and the corresponding link:

```
def get_stock_news(ticker):
    requested_stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    news = requested_stock.news
    news_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['title', 'link'])
    for i in range(3):
        news_df.loc[i] = [news[i]['title'], news[i]['link']]

    return news_df
```

After that my app callback and the update function look like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('company_image', 'src'),
    Output('company_name', 'children'),
    Output('ceo', 'children'),
    Output('hq', 'children'),
    Output('employees', 'children'),
    Output('symbol', 'children'),
    Output('headline_one', 'children'),
    Output('headline_two', 'children'),
    Output('headline_three', 'children'),
    [Input('dow_jones_dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_requested_company(value):
    image = get_requested_image(value)
    name = get_requested_name(value)
    ceo = get_requested_ceo(value)
    hq = get_requested_hq(value)
    employees = get_requested_employees(value)
    symbol = get_requested_symbol(value)
    news = get_stock_news(value)
    headline_one = news.loc[0]['title']
    headline_two = news.loc[1]['title']
    headline_three = news.loc[2]['title']
    return image, name, ceo, hq, employees, symbol, headline_one, headline_two, headline_three
```

Now I would like to set the value in the html part like this (the href part is pseudo code)

```
html.Div(children=[
            html.H5('Related news:', style= {'display': 'inline-block', 'margin-right': '10px', 'margin-bottom': '0px', 'margin-top': '0px'}),
            html.Link(id='headline_one', style= {'display': 'inline-block'}, href='link_one')
        ]),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(children=[
            html.Link(id='headline_two', style= {'display': 'inline-block'}, href='link_two')
        ]),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(children=[
            html.Link(id='headline_three', style= {'display': 'inline-block'}, href='link_three')
        ]),
```

I tried returning the links in the `update_requested_company` function which did not work obviously, but I don't know how else I could send the corresponding hyperlink to the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
headline_one = news.loc[0]['title']
```

why can't you also have

```
link_one = news.loc[0]['link']?
```

Comment: because I cant return two values to the same id (afaik)

Comment: @Frevelman I think you can have both `Output('headline_x', 'children'),` and `Output('headline_x', 'href')`. Otherwise you could wrap each link in a div and update the div's children property by returning `html.Link(...)` (ie. you would have 3 Output instead of 6,, or you can even use one single wrapper with the 3 links inside = 1 single output).